# Pointer Arrays and Functions CPP

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays, array-initialization

I wonder If there's a way to assign a dynamic array (C style), values like in the case of a non dynamic array (instead of `matrix[0][0] = ...`), e.g.:

```
int n = 3;
int ** matrix = new int*[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
     matrix[i] = new int[n];
}

matrix =  {{1,1,1},{2,0,2},{3,3,3}};
```

And how would I pass the non dynamic array `int matrix[3][3] = {{1,1,1},{2,0,2},{3,3,3}};` to a function like  `void printmatrix(int **matrix, int n)`?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` and `std::array`?

Comment: @MooingDuck dunno, are there disadvantages in O time or space?

Comment: not if you use them correctly, no

Comment: `std::array` is a zero-cost abstraction over a C array.

Comment: [Here is a simple `vector` based, high speed matrix implementation that is nearly foolproof.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I wonder If there's a way to assign a dynamic array (in c), values like in the case of a non dynamic array (instead of `matrix[0][0] = ...`)*

For 2D arrays, only on declaration, *e.g.*:

```
int matrix[][3] = {{1,1,1},{2,0,2},{3,3,3}};
```

Or

```
int matrix[][3]{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {3, 3, 3}};
```

Value initialization of arrays is allowed.
After that you can't, `matrix` is not a modifiable lvalue, you can't directly assing values in such fashion.

Later adding values is [exactly the same in both situations](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qxptCj30FnEf3s4X), using `matrix[0][0] = ...`, this is valid for both 2D arrays and for pointer to pointer allocations, it's a fine substitute for pointer dereference notation I might add.

> *And how would I pass the non dynamic array `int matrix[3][3] =  {{1,1,1},{2,0,2},{3,3,3}};` to a function like void `printmatrix(int **matrix, int n)`?*

It can't be done, one is a pointer to pointer to `int`, the other is an array of arrays of `int`s, *aka* a 2D array of `int`'s, these are incompatible, you cannot pass any one of them to an argument of the other.

At most you can pass an array of pointers, *i.e.* `int* matrix[SIZE]` can be passed to an argument of type `int **matrix`, and this is because the array will decay to a pointer when passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

As had previously been mentioned,this kind of assignment is not possible in C++.Each element of a matrix is just a pointer to an element of type int.

[image]

This image shows what are you trying to do when you dynamically allocate a matrix.Dynamic allocation is used when you have to give values to matrix fields at runtime,for example you get data from the user with std::cin and then you populate a matrix with that data dynamically.